# How to save CountryOrRegion to a contact with Exchange WebService

Tags: .net, exchangewebservices

we are going to use an exchange server in the next time, so I want to recode our contact import.

The old one uses the Outlook.Interop library to create contacts in a defined folder:

```
    Dim ci As ContactItem
    ci = f.Items.Add(OlItemType.olContactItem)
    ci.FirstName = ByNull(row("FirstName"))
    ci.LastName = ByNull(row("LastName"))
    ci.BusinessAddressCountry = ByNull(row("CountryName"))
    ci.Save()
```

but now, I want to save the the contacts via Exchange managed API:

```
    Dim c As New Contact(svc)
    Dim pae As New PhysicalAddressEntry()

    pae.Street = ByNull(row("BusinessAddressStreet"))
    pae.PostalCode = ByNull(row("BusinessAddressPostalCode"))
    pae.City = ByNull(row("BusinessAddressCity"))
    pae.CountryOrRegion = ByNull(row("CountryName"))

    c.PhysicalAddresses(PhysicalAddressKey.Business) = pae
    c.PostalAddressIndex = PhysicalAddressIndex.Home 'fix, because it´s shown as business address
    c.Save()
```

It works fine, except the shown country within the country/region column in outlook, because it is empty. (Contacts->View->List)

Screenshot:
[Outlook People](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxx9rfcr2uowe2t/outlook.png?dl=0)

But when I save the contact again via Outlook, the country appears within the column.

I´ve searched for some property like Contact.CountryOrRegion, but this doesn´t exist.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You may try to use any low-level property viewer such as MFCMAPI or Outlook Spy for exploring hidden properties. As for the EWS, you may find the [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) article helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also set the pidTagCountry extended property for this property to show in the Address book view https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee201020(v=exchg.80).aspx

eg

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_BUSINESS_ADDRESS_COUNTRY = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3A26, MapiPropertyType.String);
        ContactObject.SetExtendedProperty(PR_BUSINESS_ADDRESS_COUNTRY, "Australia");
```

The strongly typed property only set this pidLidWorkAddress property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee178066(v=exchg.80).aspx

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thats exactly what I´ve searched for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The address/country/zip shown on the grid (Contacts->View->List) is from the mailing address of the contact. You need to update 3 extended properties to synchronize these 3 fields to the contact's mailing address: Mailing Address, Country/Region and Zip. The full code snippet is like this:

```
//MAILING ADDRESS
ExtendedPropertyDefinition MAILING_ADDRESS = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition    (0x3A15, MapiPropertyType.String);
contact.SetExtendedProperty(MAILING_ADDRESS, "[Street][, City][, State/Province][ ZIP/Postal code][, Country/Region if not United States]");

//COUNTRY/REGION
ExtendedPropertyDefinition MAILING_ADDRESS_COUNTRY = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3A26, MapiPropertyType.String);
contact.SetExtendedProperty(MAILING_ADDRESS_COUNTRY, "[Country/Region]");

//ZIP/POSTAL CODE
ExtendedPropertyDefinition MAILING_ADDRESS_ZIP = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3A2A, MapiPropertyType.String);
contact.SetExtendedProperty(MAILING_ADDRESS_ZIP, "[ZIP/Postal code]");
```

Here [] means the specified element within the brackets will be omitted if the value is empty for that element.